# how to get result from executing a set of system commands in a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am running a set of system commands in my Ruby script , and I would like to get the result (true /false) of the execution  ( as I already did for a single command

```
  unless system("mkdir -p #{project_path}")
     puts "Cannot create local project directory." 
     exit 1
 end
```

for a set of commands I tried :

```
unless system <<EOC
  cp "#{dockerfile_template}" "#{project_path}"
  cd "#{project_path}"
  git init .
  git add -A
  git commit -m "first commit" 
  git remote add origin "#{project_repository}"
  git push -u origin master
EOC
exit 1
end
```

but it's failing : =>  an't find string "EOC" anywhere before EOF
any suggestion welcome ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Can you give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? One that doesn't rely on undefined variables and git repositories.

Comment: thanks for looking at it... I solved the issue changing the writing ... the git commands are executed ... raising another issue I'll post in another question...  read my own answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the writing issue , using the %x[ ] writing :

```
  output = %x[ 
    cp "#{dockerfile_template}" "#{project_path}"
    cd "#{project_path}"
    git init
    git add -A
    git commit -m "first commit" 
    git remote add origin "#{project_repository}"
    git push -u origin master
  ]
```